# Unable to create flutter project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Kernel binary: invalid kernel binary format version. 
I get this error when i try to create the flutter project in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try "flutter clean". But this might not help.
I'm no expert but if this doesn't help you'll probably end up uninstalling and reinstalling Flutter.